# System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection settings work fine in Debug and Release but crash on Deployment?

Tags: c#, list, settings, clickonce, stringcollection

For my latest WPF application, I've been using an `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` to save and load strings. My current system works like a charm in Debug and Release, but when deployed to ClickOnce, the application crashes as soon as anything involving the settings are involved (loading or saving)! However, `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollections` work just fine on their own if not a setting.

What could be causing these crashes?

Here are my systems:

```
    public static void SaveCharacter(string code)
        {
            // Declare a blank StringCollection
            StringCollection strings = new StringCollection();

            // Convert the current settings StringCollection into an array and combine with the blank one
            if (Settings.Default.SavedCharacters.Count > 0)
            {
                string[] tempArr= new string[Settings.Default.SavedCharacters.Count];
                Settings.Default.SavedCharacters.CopyTo(tempArr, 0);
                strings.AddRange(tempArr);
            }

            // Add the new string to the list
            strings.Add(code);

            // This new list is now saved as the setting itself
            Settings.Default.SavedCharacters = strings;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

```
        public static void RestoreCharacters()
        {
            foreach (string str in Settings.Default.SavedCharacters)
            {
                CreateCharacter(str, "l" + ID.ToString()); // This function works fine
                ID++; // So does this variable (it's a public static)
            }
        }
```

P.S. I tried a similar system with `List<string>` items, but no dice. Other settings involving `strings`, `bools` and `ints` work fine though.

P.P.S. Sidenote, does anyone know how to combine `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollections` without having to convert one to an array?

Comment: What is the Exception when it crashes? Windows or the Runtime have to give you *something*. A likely culptript would be trust. ClickOnce is the kind of environment where only the highest level of trusted code can run.

Comment: can you do try / catch to get the exception logged somewhere?

Comment: There I two articles on proper Exception handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | However I do not think you need extra code to get the Exception. The framework is awesome at making sure unhandeled Exceptions are logged somewhere. The Windows logs, when in doubt.  But a explicit logging and exposing can still help.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Christopher and @Jawad! I managed to get the exception, and it goes as follows: ```System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Taskit.CharacterWindowManagement.SaveCharacter(String code)```. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case anyone else gets stuck with such an annoying bug! Before you can operate on a User Setting that has to be `newed()`, you need to create an instance of it to utilise instead. For example:

`StringCollection foo = Settings.Default.SavedCharacters;`

When it comes to saving such collections, simply using `Settings.Default.SavedCharacters = foo;` works fine!